# Validar contraseñas en Formulario con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación, login, contraseña

necesito validar un Formulario y quiero que como condición, las contraseñas sean iguales para avanzar o si son distintas, darle 3 oportunidades al usuario. ¿No me funciona, donde me estoy equivocando?
Gracias

```
var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
var pass1 = document.getElementById("passwordR").value;
if (nombre == "" || apellido == "" || telefono == "" || email == "" || pass == "" || 
pass1 == "") {
            alert("Debes completar Todos los campos");
            } else if (pass !== pass1) {
              alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.!!");
               for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                   document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true;                    
            }
                return;

            } else {
                document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false;
                alert("Cuenta Creada Correctamente, presione Aceptar para continuar...");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Te sale algun error??

Answer (score 3):

El `for` no está haciendo nada, realmente. Solo está deshabilitando 3 veces el botón `#enviar`.

Tienes que replantearte el proceso para tener claro lo que intentas hacer. No se trata de **comparar 3 veces las contraseñas en un mismo intento**, sino de **comparar las contraseñas una sola vez en 3 intentos**. El `for` no tiene ninguna utilidad.

Lo que necesitas es almacenar de alguna forma el número de intentos en algún sitio fuera del ámbito de tu validación (una cookie, una variable global, la base de datos, etc) y comparar las contraseñas UN VEZ, cada vez que el usuario intente enviar el formulario. Ejemplo:

```javascript
var intentos = 0;

function validar() {
    if (intentos <= 3) {
        var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("passwordR").value;
        if ( nombre == "" ||
             apellido == "" ||
             telefono == "" ||
             email == "" ||
             pass == "" ||
             pass1 == ""
        ) {
            alert("Debes completar Todos los campos");
        } else if (pass !== pass1) {
            alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.!!");
            intentos++;
        } else {
            alert("Cuenta Creada Correctamente, presione Aceptar para continuar...");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Has alcanzado el máximo número de intentos.!!");
    }
}
```

Las iteraciones que tu intuición te hacía creer que se correspondían con un `for` se refieren realmente a cada una de las ejecuciones de la función `validar()`. Pero no hay nada automatizado ahí... Las iteraciones las provoca el propio usuario cada vez que hace "click" en `#enviar`.

Nota: Omití las habilitaciones/deshabilitaciones del botón porque eso es algo que también deberás revisar con calma.

Comment: Muchas Graciassss

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo resolvi de esta Forma y funciona muy bien, igualmente gracias por tu aporte:

```
<script>
        function activateSend() {
            document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false;
        }

        function singinClick() {
            var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
            var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
            var telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var pass1 = document.getElementById("passwordR").value;
            if (nombre == "" || apellido == "" || telefono == "" || email == "" || pass == "" || pass1 == "") {
                alert("Debes completar Todos los campos");
            } else if (pass !== pass1) {
                alert("Las contraseñas no coinciden.!!");
                document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true;
                setTimeout(activateSend, 1000);
            } else {
                alert("Cuenta Creada Correctamente, presione Aceptar para continuar...");
            }
        }
                
    </script>
```